# PDO not pulling data from string but works fine with integer

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pdo

I'm trying to build a single pages.php file which I can pass slug information too and use mod-rewrite to make database output look like actual pages.

The problem is that the code works but only with integers being passed. If I pass the page_id it will make the call and work, if I pass page_slug it will fail.

Here is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^service/(.*)$ pages.php?pid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And here is the select query in pages.php to which I'm using require_once("Database.php"); to call the database file.

```
$sql = " 
      SELECT 
         page_title,
         page_html_title,
         page_slug,
         page_content
     FROM pages
     WHERE page_slug = $pid
        ";

    $q = $db->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $r = $q->fetch();
```

The data is put into html in following matter {$r['page_title']}

> Paste for pages.php  http://pastebin.com/qA7zzvnY
>
> Paste for Database.php http://pastebin.com/8pqXbzby

Here is database tables
[image]

Known problem.

> SELECT page_slug

returns empty page, with no error or source code anywhere.

> SELECT page_id

returns the page truth pages.php?pid=zzzzzz or rewrite service/zzzzz.html I'm not sure why I can't pull page slug from database when I have done it in past with usernames and other random data. But in the provided $sql code it does not want to work.

Comment: And how are the fields of your table declared? Also, on a side note, why not use prepared statements, since you're already using PDO?

Comment: @Havelock I'm doing $r['field_name']. I'm not very strong with PDO, sadly I hate it as it make my life hell

Comment: What error are you experiencing? Also, as Havelock said, make sure you use prepared statements otherwise you are an easy target for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What I meant is to rather update your question with the definition of your MySQL table, i.e. `field_name|type` and more specifically `page_title|varchar(40)`, etc

Comment: @Havelock page_title|varchar(88)

Comment: What happens when you go to service/1 ?  Also, you mention both "service" and "services", are you mistyping one of them?

Comment: When I type in service/1 it loads the page, loads all needed stuff into crumbread and ect other then css failing nothing else is wrong

Comment: Well, what did you mean by "service/1 would not work"? Now you seem to be saying it is working.

Comment: @kojow7 I got that working, I did some htaccess cleanup and removed few lines that were turning .php to .html so service/1 would actually need to be service/1.html but it will come back with 404 saying 1.php is not found.

Comment: @kojow7 the problem is still not in my rewrite. Its when you use `FROM page_slug = $pid` that things seem to break. If you just use regular page_id it works fine. Even with rewrite using a slug will just load a blank screen but no error or source code.

Comment: If you solve something, you should post it here so people aren't still trying to help you with an issue that no longer exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76118/discussion-between-kojow7-and-c1ph3r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need single quotes (or properly escaped double quotes) around `$pid` in the query. Also, as pointed out in the comments, you are wide open to SQL injection and need to address that immediately.

Comment: I'm aware, i'm a new comer to PDO. And sadly I don't like it much compared to old mysql_